# Connect to WIFI from Chrome while in kiosk mode

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, kiosk

I have a small setup, where a windows tablet starts up and automatically loads a webpage in Chrome, in kiosk mode. But the webpage requires WIFI to work (Ethernet cable is not an option), is there anyway i can connect to WIFI without quitting the Chrome Kiosk? Maybe a Chrome plugin or a windows application that pops up if no internet is detected.

The goal is simply to connect to WIFI without quitting the Chrome kiosk.

Answer (score 0):

If the Wi-Fi you need to access is always the same, you've just to configure it once taking care of enabling the "Automatically connect" option. From then on you simply won't need to do it again.

Comment: Its not the same, its most likely different everytime the tablet is in use.

Answer (score -1):

I confirmed this. You will need to login to the local non kiosk account and check the "connect automatically" box and then connect to the wifi. Then reboot and when it will auto login to the kiosk and it should connect to the wifi automatically.